# How to display a tooltip on form elements in Angular Material

Tags: angular-material

I need to display help info against some fields as on the picture.

[image]

I imagine the `<md-tooltip>` would the most appropriate for this. However the hint icon doesn't tone it and it fails in the second line.

Answer (score 1):

So far I get the following solution http://codepen.io/adambubela/pen/JXzzaV?editors=1000

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" layout="column" layout-padding="" ng-cloak="" class="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content>
    <div layout>
          <md-input-container class="md-block" flex>
              <label>Name</label>
              <input ng-model="user.name" type="text">
          </md-input-container>
           <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="help" style="margin-top:22px">
             <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_person_24px.svg" class="name"></md-icon>
             <md-tooltip md-direction="bottom">We need to know how to call you</md-tooltip>
           </md-button>
      </div
  </md-content>
</div>
```

However I get inpression it is not very elegant as it requires many nested elements.

Comment: It seems to work as well when you place the `<md-tooltip>` directly inside the `<div layout>` ?